# Generating IDs for Items in an Inventory System

Tags: c#

So I am making an inventory system as a school project and I want to generate a Unique IDs for the items so that it will be the identifier for that certain Item.

Is it possible to generate an ID which is based on certain fields such as the item name, the price, the expiration.

Is there some existing library I can use for this?

EDIT: It is okay for my system to have duplicate ids because it will mean that the item already exists in the system and does not need to be added again.

Comment: Just generate the next number in a sequence.  What is the value in generating an ID based on those fields?

Comment: If by _"unique ID"_ you mean _serial number_ then you wouldn't want to use _"price"_.  You could use _"expiration"_ for say the ID for a group of products (Product ID).  Price isn't a useful sub-domain

Comment: @Amy The OP specifically asked how to generate a unique identifier from existing information - they made no mention of using a surrogate identifier.

Comment: @dai I am aware of that.  They're also a student.

Comment: Is there any point of wanting to generating the id based on existing information?

Comment: @TomDee Yes: Content-Addressable Storage. It's how Git, BitTorrent (Distributed Hashtables), and Bitcoin all work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate an ID which is based on certain fields such as the item name, the price, the expiration.

Yes: a hash.

For example:

```
// It's very important to use `InvariantCulture ` and "o" to ensure consistent formatting on all computers
String infoText = item.Name + item.Price.ToString( "C2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) + item.Expiration.ToString("o");
Byte[] infoBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( infoText );

using( SHA256 sha = new SHA256Cng() )
{
    Byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash( infoBytes );
    String hashText = Convert.ToBase64String( hash );
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} = {1}", infoText, hashText )
}
```

A hash (also known as a "digest") will always be the same for the same input, and will be different for different input.

So if you have an SKU containing $10 worth of apples that expires on 2019-10-09, and you feed that in to the code above, then it will generate a unique code you can use without needing to store the mapping between that SKU and that unique code (also known as "content-based addressing").

...so if you come across another $10 worth of apples that also expire on 2019-10-09, then it will have the same unique code, even though it's a different object, and you didn't need to memorize that unique code you generated earlier.

But if you come across $10 worth of pears that expires on 2019-10-09, or $20 worth of apples that also expires on the same day, the'll have a different code.

Comment: how about generating a guid based on the data?

```public Guid Hash(string input)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                return new Guid(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input)));
        }```

Comment: @rm.szc81 Never do that. Your code just takes an MD5 hash and tells the computer to interpret it as a GUID - but an MD5 hash isn't a GUID, even though it has the same length. That's like telling a computer to interpret a 64-bit integer representing the size of a file on disk as a `DateTime` because you can construct a `DateTime` from `Int64 ticks`.

Comment: @rm.szc81 Also, MD5 is cryptographically insecure and has very little use in 2015 (if you want a fast hash use Murmur, if you want a secure hash use SHA-2).

Comment: but if the intention is just to make "unique" hash, there's no need to make it secure like sha or other strong algorithm. of course my example can have some collisions but, using stronger algorithms are really necessary for this case?

Comment: @rm.szc81 I would have used Murmurhash in my example, but .NET doesn't have a built-in implementation of Murmurhash - and if someone is going to learn about Hashes by copying-and-pasting my posting (let's face it, someone will) then they should learn about modern hashing algorithms, not obsolete and insecure algos.

Comment: my point is about the need of secure the information, not about the algos being obsolete or insecure.

Comment: thank you so much this is what I just need for the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the ID by concatenating all of the information together as a big string or even hashing that string.

However this can still give you duplicates if all of that information is that same several times. There doesn't seem to be any need on using the existing information to generate the ID. If you are basing it on existing data then there will always be a chance of duplicates. Unless there is some sort of constraint on one of the fields requiring that to be unique. But if that's unique then you could just use that as an ID in the first place.

If you are storing this data in a database I would suggest creating an ID field and make that the primary key and give it an identity. This will automatically increment the ID so it will always be unique.

You could also just generate a GUID by using `Guid.NewGuid()` and use that as the ID.

Comment: "However this can still give you duplicates if all of that information is that same several times" - that's **intentional** and can be a desirable (if not outright required) behaviour depending on the OP's system design.

Comment: @Dai the first sentence of the question says the IDs should be unique.

Comment: The OP doesn't say IDs should be unique when duplicate item information appears - they left that requirement undefined.

Comment: if there's the intention to "unhash" and get the original string, I think that just a base64 would be enough IF there's no need to encrypt the information.

Comment: @Dai I definitely read it as it always has to be unique even if it's the same item details however yes it is a bit ambiguous

Comment: @rm.szc81 Concatenating the data results in strings of varying length - possibly of unbounded length too, and they won't be evenly distributed in the namespace which makes them unsuitable for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to generate an ID which is based on certain fields such as the item name, the price, the expiration.

Joining these three strings or even hashing them still have the chance of being duplicate. 
Simple question needs simple solution, why not using a running number? Since you have an inventory system, for the first item in your inventory system that should be `ID#1` (or you can start with any numbers you like).

But if you insist to use certain fields information i would suggest that adding all below information together:

1. combination of fields information
2. timestamp
3. user id(person who perform the insert)
4. maybe your favorite colors
5. hashing all information above